# SQL insert error

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-error-1064

```
 $query = "INSERT INTO event (eventDesc) ".
          "VALUES ('".$eventDesc."') WHERE event = 'Testing'";
```

is there something wrong with this statement?

I'm getting error saying:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE event = 'Testing'' at line 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use an UPDATE statement to update an existing value:

```
$query = sprintf("UPDATE EVENT
                     SET eventDesc = '%s'  
                   WHERE event = 'Testing'",
                  mysql_real_escape_string($eventDesc));
```

This is safer than your query -- no [risk of SQL injection attack](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a WHERE clause in an INSERT query.

Comment: There is if the values are supplied using a SELECT - IE: `INSERT INTO EVENT SELECT col FROM OTHER_TABLE WHERE ...`

Comment: That is not a WHERE clause on the INSERT query, it is a WHERE clause in the SELECT query.

Comment: I think you (and whomever upvoted your comment) need to look a little closer at my example.

Comment: I think I understood it. INSERT INTO ... SELECT inserts the result of the SELECT query. The SELECT query in your example has a WHERE clause. It is not a WHERE clause on the INSERT query. It acts on the table(s) in the SELECT, not the table(s) on the INSERT.